# How can one efficiently do the equivalent of Excel's MATCH function (less than) in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, match, vlookup

The MATCH function in excel allows an optional parameter set which will return either the greatest value less than a given value, or the lowest value greater than a given value.

Let's say I have a DataFrame, `x`.

```
In [1]: x = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(0, 11)), columns=["Obs"])

In [2]: x
Out[2]:
    Obs
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10   10
```

And a dataframe, `y`.

```
In [3]: y = pd.DataFrame(data=[(-1, "Small"), (4, "Medium"), (7, "Large")], 
                         columns=["Obs", "Cat"])

In [4]: y
Out[4]:
Obs     Cat
0   -1   Small
1    4  Medium
2    7   Large
```

How can I do a INDEX-MATCH with a match_type of 1, meaning it will go through each of the values in Obs, and return the value of of "Cat" that corresponds to the "Obs" which is the largest value that is less than and equal to the lookup?

Note that I'd like to do this in some vectorized way and NOT write a custom function and loop through the rows of the second DataFrame. That would be rather inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want `pd.merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(x, y)
```

Comment: or resort to pd.merge if you're using a version of pandas below 0.19.0

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `cut`, less compact but it gives you ordered categorical for free:

```
pd.cut(x.Obs, y.Obs.tolist()+[np.inf], labels=y.Cat)
Out[362]: 
0      Small
1      Small
2      Small
3      Small
4      Small
5     Medium
6     Medium
7     Medium
8      Large
9      Large
10     Large
Name: Obs, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Small < Medium < Large]
```